# Access To first List View After going to Thrid List view

Tags: android

I have a question about list view which confused me completely.

I am going to design a app for play songs my favortie singer and below is my implements:

AlbumActivity----->ItemActivity(contain songs)---->PlayerActivity

This is my Album activity code:

```
public class AlbumActivity extends Activity implements Variable {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.album_list);



    populatecantactlist();//fill listview with my item
    registerClickCallback();//What to do when click on item


  }

private void populatecantactlist() {


    ListView listview=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new mylistAdapter();

    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

}

public class mylistAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    private  mylistAdapter(){
        super(AlbumActivity.this,R.layout.album_list_item,albumnames);
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent){

        View item_view=convertView;

        if(item_view== null){             item_view=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.album_list_item,parent,false);
        }

        ImageView iv=(ImageView)item_view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        iv.setImageResource(icon_num[position]);

        TextView tv1=(TextView)item_view.findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
        tv1.setText(albumnames[position]);

        return item_view;}

    }







     private void registerClickCallback() {

    ListView list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    //I want to after on each item select go to new activity which populate 
        //information about new album

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewclicked,
                int position, long id) {

            Intent i2=new Intent("com.example.ItemActivity");




            Bundle extras=new Bundle();
            extras.putInt("PositionItemClicked", position);
            i2.putExtras(extras);


            startActivity(i2);


        }});
```

and this is also my item Activity:

note:I define album name first in arrays with relate names.

```
String [] names;
int  icon_num;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.album_list);



    Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();
    int i=bundle.getInt("PositionItemClicked");

    switch (i){

    case 0:
        names=name1;
        icon_num=R.drawable.name1;
        break;
    case 1:
        names=name2;
        icon_num=R.drawable.name2;
        break;
    case 2:
        names=name3;
        icon_num=R.drawable.name3;
        break;
    case 3:
        names=name4;
        icon_num=R.drawable.name4;
        break;
    case 4:
        names=name5;
        icon_num=R.drawable.name5;
        break;
    case 5:
        names=name6;
        icon_num=R.drawable.name6;
        break;
    case 6:
        names=name7;
        icon_num=R.drawable.name7;
        break;
    case 7:
        names=name8;
        icon_num=R.drawable.name8;
        break;

    case 8:
        names=name9;
        icon_num=R.drawable.name9;
        break;
    case 9:
        names=name10;
        icon_num=R.drawable.name10;
        break;
    case 10:
        names=name11;
        icon_num=R.drawable.name11;
        break;
    case 11:
        names=name12;
        icon_num=R.drawable.name12;
        break;

    }


    populatecantactlist();//fill listview with my item
    registerClickCallback();//What to do when click on item



}



public void populatecantactlist() {


    ListView listview=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new mylistAdapter();

    listview.setAdapter(adapter);


}

public class mylistAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{



    private  mylistAdapter(){

        super(ItemActivity.this,R.layout.album_list_item,names);
    }





    @Override
    public View getView(int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent){

        View item_view=convertView;

        if(item_view== null){

            item_view=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.album_list_item,parent,false);
        }

        ImageView iv=(ImageView)item_view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        iv.setImageResource(icon_num);

        TextView tv1=(TextView)item_view.findViewById(R.id.txt_name);

        tv1.setText(names[position]);

        return item_view;
        }

    }

private void registerClickCallback() {

    final ListView list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    //I want to after on each item select go to new activity which populate with
        //information about new album

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewclicked,
                int position, long id) {





            Intent i3=new Intent("com.example.PlayerActivity");

            Bundle extras=new Bundle();
            extras.putInt("i",list.getCount());
            i3.putExtras(extras);

            startActivity(i3);




        }});
```

and it is my PlayerActivity:

```
 public class PlayerActivity extends Activity implements Variable {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.player_layout);


    Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();
    int i=bundle.getInt("i");

     Toast.makeText(PlayerActivity.this,"hello"+i,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

     }}
```

But i can't  know item selected in itemactivity belong to what album(means Album Activity)?And now After one day i Don't know what to do?
Do you think it is a complex manner ,can you guide me to a better manner?

Thanks.

Comment: In your AlbumActivity, how exactly do you figure out which songs to display, you must pass some kind of parameter so that it knows which songs should be displayed in the lsit right?

Comment: i don't know your mind.I use intent to pass data about item selected to next activity (means ItemActivity)..!

Comment: You Got me The Key!!!!Below is answer...

Answer (score 0):

Just change item activity to this:

```
  String [] names;
  int  icon_num;

  Bundle bundle;


 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.album_list);



bundle=getIntent().getExtras();
int i=bundle.getInt("PositionItemClicked");

switch (i){

case 0:
    names=name1;
    icon_num=R.drawable.name1;
    break;
case 1:
    names=name2;
    icon_num=R.drawable.name2;
    break;
case 2:
    names=name3;
    icon_num=R.drawable.name3;
    break;
case 3:
    names=name4;
    icon_num=R.drawable.name4;
    break;
case 4:
    names=name5;
    icon_num=R.drawable.name5;
    break;
case 5:
    names=name6;
    icon_num=R.drawable.name6;
    break;
case 6:
    names=name7;
    icon_num=R.drawable.name7;
    break;
case 7:
    names=name8;
    icon_num=R.drawable.name8;
    break;

case 8:
    names=name9;
    icon_num=R.drawable.name9;
    break;
case 9:
    names=name10;
    icon_num=R.drawable.name10;
    break;
case 10:
    names=name11;
    icon_num=R.drawable.name11;
    break;
case 11:
    names=name12;
    icon_num=R.drawable.name12;
    break;

}


populatecantactlist();//fill listview with my item
registerClickCallback();//What to do when click on item



 }



  public void populatecantactlist() {


ListView listview=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new mylistAdapter();

listview.setAdapter(adapter);


}

 public class mylistAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{



private  mylistAdapter(){

    super(ItemActivity.this,R.layout.album_list_item,names);
}





@Override
public View getView(int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent){

    View item_view=convertView;

    if(item_view== null){

          item_view=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.album_list_item,parent,false);
    }

    ImageView iv=(ImageView)item_view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    iv.setImageResource(icon_num);

    TextView tv1=(TextView)item_view.findViewById(R.id.txt_name);

    tv1.setText(names[position]);

    return item_view;
    }

}

private void registerClickCallback() {

final ListView list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
//I want to after on each item select go to new activity which populate with
    //information about new album

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewclicked,
            int position, long id) {





        Intent i3=new Intent("com.example.PlayerActivity");

        Bundle extras=new Bundle();
        extras.putInt("i",bundle.getInt("PositionItemClicked");
        i3.putExtras(extras);

        startActivity(i3);




    }});
```